# How to manage User-Profile creation

Tags: python, django

I want to create an extended User model. I've created a profile model with a one-to-one relationship with the default django User model. The problem is that when I create a Profile instance and I include the User field it raises me the (NOT NULL constraint failed: portal_profile.user_id) excetion. Why?

view.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form= UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile_form.user=user_form
            profile_form.save()
```

model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    img = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='userImg')
    country = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
 class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
        img=forms.ImageField(required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields=['img', 'country', 'city', 'email']
```

register.html

```
{% if UserForm.errors or  ProfileFrom.errros %}
        <p> Error </p>
{% endif %}


{{ UserForm }}
{{ ProfileForm }}
```

Comment: The `ProfileForm` doesn't seem to have anything related to user, while it's required in your Model

Comment: `profile_form.user=user_form` this line is the problem, your user is not getting added. I suggest you to use signals to create profile. A better way is to remove profile form from the sign up page. Do sign up only with your user form and, when you will save user the signal will create a profile for that user and then in next page show profile form with a option to skip.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing model instances with forms in both the case of the user and the profile. It should be:

```
user = user_form.save()
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```